# Manipulating ActiveRecord objects to build JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, activerecord

We're trying to load a webpage faster. The main issue is about a few activerecord-generated queries on that page.

If you look at the SQL they generate (Postgres), the queries are as follows (all code a bit simplified):

```
select * from feed_details where account_id = 5
select * from feeds where id in (VERY_LONG_LIST_OF_IDS_FROM_FIRST_QUERY)
select * from feeds_metadata where feed_id in (VERY_LONG_LIST_FROM_FIRST_QUERY)
select * from documents where feed_id in (VERY_LONG_LIST_FROM_FIRST_QUERY)
```

All the indexes are in place, but we verified that they'd take less than half the time by changing them to:

```
select * from feeds, feed_details where id = feed_id and account_id = 5
select * from feeds_metadata fm, feed_details fd where fm.feed_id = fd.feed_id and account_id = 5
select * from documents where d, feed_details fd where d.feed_id = fd.feed_id and account_id = 5
```

So far, so simple. Here is the Rails issue: these queries have been generated by this code in the FeedDetail model:

```
class FeedDetail < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :feeds
  has_many :feeds_metadata
  has_many :documents

  scope :feeds_data_for_account, ->(current_account_id) do
    FeedDetail
              .includes(:feeds, :feeds_metadata, :documents)
              .where(
                  account_id: current_account_id
              )
  end
```

This generates an active record object (with the data from the above-mentioned queries), that is used in the controller to build the JSON that is sent to the webpage as in below (see feeds_data line):

```
  def index
    consumer          = ConsumerWithAccount.new(current_user.account)
    feed_builder      = FeedBuilder
    feeds_data        = FeedDetail.feeds_data_for_account(current_user.account.id)

    render json: ResponseBuilder.new(consumer, feed_builder, feeds_data)
  end
```

To use the faster queries, we were hoping to build the feeds_data activerecord object that is passed to the JSON builder by using the faster queries. That would involve getting rid of the "involves", which (seemingly) uses the IN () in SQL.

If useful, we have the correct queries per each of the 3 data sources in activerecord, they look like:

```
Feed.joins(:feed_details).where(feed_document_sets: {account_id: current_account_id})
```

But we couldn't figure out how to build that activerecord object: therein lies the proverbial rub.

The plan B is to re-write the responsebuilder to take a different type of object, but that looks like more complicated.

The person who wrote this is no longer with the company.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: could try using `preload` instead of `includes'